# Getting error in Adding Image in List View with text

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

In my Android App, I am trying to display content of my database table in a list view and it is working perfectly.. and gives a output like this,

[image]

This is my method by which I am calling all names from Table,

```
public void getAllPartiesName()
{
    try
    {
        db=new DBAdapter(PartyNamesActivity.this);
        db.open();
        c=db.getAllPartiesName();
        partiesnamelist=new ArrayList<String>();
        if(c.getCount()>0)
        {                                
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    partiesnamelist.add(c.getString(0));
                } 
                while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Names Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(PartyNamesActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,partiesnamelist);
    lvpartiesname.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But when I am trying to add a custom layout to the ListView, its giving error,
Actually I want to display a Image with every List View name on the Left side...
So, I have used custom layout..

That Custom Layout is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Text of List-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="List View Name"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And After adding this layout I changed the code of `Array Adapter` like this,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(PartyNamesActivity.this,R.layout.list_row,partiesnamelist);
lvpartiesname.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And here I am getting problem, (gives this error)

My LogCat,

```
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at    android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
11-01 10:01:43.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10968):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
```

Please help me,

Thanks.

Comment: replace `R.layout.list_row` by `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` or override `getView` of Adapter and inflate the custom layout and use the same assuming `partiesnamelist` is a string array list

Comment: @Raghunandan: How to use getView ?? Actually I dont have any idea about this..

Comment: do you how to use a custom adapter?

Comment: @Raghunandan: No :( I only know that Adapter which I have used in my this code and that 1 worked properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom adapter. CutomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter. In `getView` you inflate a custom layout and return the view. Using ViewHolder pattern for smooth scrolling and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Pass the activity context and the arraylist to the constructor of custom adapter and make use of the same there.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names.size();
    }
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<String> naems;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> partiesnamelist) {
        super(context, 0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        names= partiesnamelist;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
            // inflate layout 
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // use the view object to initialize views
        holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else { 
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    } 
        holder.tv.setText(names.get(position)); 
            // set text to textview usinf position adn arraylist names
            // set image to imageview using position
        return convertView;
    }
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
}
}
```

Then in Activtiy

```
CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this,partiesnamelist);
lvpartiesname.setAdapter(cus);
```

list_item.xml // single relative layout is enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="List View Name"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do I have to create a new class `CustomAdapter` and what I have to pass in this line..
`holder.tv.setText(names.get(position)); ` ?? My arraylist name `partiesnamelist` ??

Comment: @Shiv yes create a new class pass arraylist here `CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this,partiesnamelist)`;  in your activity

Comment: @Shiv and look at the constructor have you looked at the code firs tor just copy pasting from my post? `public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> partiesnamelist)` and check this `names= partiesnamelist;`

Comment: Now I have Images in my `assets` folder. So, Can I use that Images..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40371/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shiv)

Comment: Accepted :)

I have a code that can fetch images from assets folder..
Wait I m adding that in comment..